# Lock the screen of an android device using code

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been reading a lot of posts that are related to how to lock the phone using the code, but all I could find is deprecated snippets from 8 years ago or comments saying is not possible, which again were fairly old.
Does anybody know if there is a way of doing it? and if there is a way, would you please be able to lead me to either the resources or give me an idea what I should do?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You mean lock as in the screen turn off and user need to input password again to use the device?

Comment: That is correct, but it will not need to input the password if it has no password

Comment: Well google been tryin' so hard to limit our control to prevent malicious app. You can't tell the system what todo. You can do workarounds like dim the screen params.screenBrightness = 0; or maybe [PowerManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager) can help. But based on my experience, this kind of stuff behaves differently across devices. So really a pain to debug.

Comment: Oh... great... 
Thanks for the advice though. I will keep the post up for a while longer, maybe a workaround comes up.

Comment: PowerManger has the methods to do this, but they are hidden from the public API.  Reflection is no use because signature permissions are required to invoke the methods.

Comment: Thanks for the Intel. I'll probably end up going with dimming the brightness and have a message on the main screen tag it would be recommended to make the phone lock itself after 30 seconds or a minute.